# ES6 reflect get constructor parameter names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I searched but didn't find if it is possible.

I have the following code:

```
class UserController {
    constructor(mailer, logger) {
    }
}
```

Basically I want to get the parameter names as strings using Reflect class in es6.

Something like that:

```
['mailer', 'logger']
```

Is it possible

I know it's possible with mad regex and parsing the whole class but I wonder if it's possible with new Reflect api.

Thanks

Comment: so do you want to return `parameters` from `constructor` it self?

Comment: no, from outside the class, for example getParamNames(UserController) will give me ['mailer', 'logger'] array

Comment: JS does not have API for accessing the names of variables or arguments. `toString` is the only option, but since minifiers and tools like Babel know that there is no API for accessing them, they treat renaming them as a safe operation. If you write code relying on `toString` it may be unusable with some of these tools.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: To make graph of the classes and parameters they use when constructing themself.

Comment: So this is for some kind of runtime analysis?

Comment: It doesnt need to be runtime, i want to create this so i can make a graph for myself if and approve the architecture if needed. I dont want to do it manually because there are a lot of classes. I can do it with class.toString and regexes but it's not as good as Reflect. If this was possible like PHP Reflection to get the names it would be good.